# Узнать путь к папке бекапа в MS SQL.

Tags: sql-server

Есть простая задача : узнать полный путь к папке Backup . Везде советуют залезть в реестр . У меня например адрес пути к этой папке лежит в реестре по следующему адресу :

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQLServer\BackupDirectory
```

Но тут есть одна загвоздка . Этот путь верен только в том случае, если на компе стоит MS SQL 2008 . Если же стоит пусть даже MS SQL Server 2008 Express , или просто SQL Server другого года , этот путь будет неверным . Тут все упирается в название папки **MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER** , которое и будет разным для разных версий SQL сервера.Пробовал еще искать какую-либо информацию в системных базах , но тоже что-то ничего дельного не нашел.К примеру в 2005 SQL Server название этой папки **MSSQL.1** . Можно конечно узнать версию ms sql запросом select @@version и прописать для каждой название этой папки,но это думаю будет неправильным. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Это имя экземпляра SQL Server, которых может быть много независимых.

Comment: Да,может,но пусть для примера на машине стоит какой-то один конкретный экземпляр сервера и для него нам нужно узнать путь к папке бекапа.

Answer (score 1):

Зачем вам нужен путь к папке Backup? И что это за папка такая?
Средствами MS SQL можно любую папку забэкапить в любое место - лишь написав скрипт бэкапа. Если вы в этой папке собираетесь найти бэкапы базы, то вряд ли это у вас получится.

Если интересно, где могут лежать бэкапы базы данных, то можно почитать вот эту статью: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188653.aspx

Comment: То, что забекапить можно в любую папку ,это понятно.Тут дело вот в чем: на удаленной машине должен выполняться скрипт бекапа и при этом я могу быть уверенными только в том , что везде есть системный диск С . Записать в любое место на этом диске не получается ибо на это нужны права .Можно вообще не указывать путь и бекап тогда и будет лежать по тому дефолтному адресу . Но потом этот бекап с удаленного компа мне нужно переслать , а для этого точно определить тот самый путь по дефолту.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE    @BackupDirectory varchar(1000)
-- get the default backup directory
EXEC master.dbo.xp_instance_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer',N'BackupDirectory',@BackupDirectory OUTPUT
```

select @BackupDirectory